# Accessing regedit without admin rights

Tags: c#

I was wondering if i could run a program without administrator rights?
I am trying to run the program regedit from System32.
I have also tried copying it onto a USB and running it from there, and both have not worked.
Can someone help me run regedit using C# script?

Comment: you can't possibly do that. It's a system level privilege.

Comment: @JW웃 How is it a "system level privilege"? Running regedit.exe can be blocked by Group Policy and, more likely, wonky UAC interactions. (However, I don't think that reg.exe suffers from either.)

Comment: @user2246674 so you mean, you can run `RegEdit` without administrator privilege?

Comment: @JW웃 I mean, *there is nothing about opening up the registry that requires Administrator Privileges* - at best this is a "misfeature" particularly related to regedit.exe (but not reg.exe, ironically). I included more details in my answer, as did sircapsalot.

Comment: @user2246674: The question asks specifically about running regedit. It doesn't ask about 'opening the registry' in any other fashion.

Comment: What is your purpose for running regedit without admin privs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answer: No, you cannot run regedit.exe without administrative privs.

What you CAN do, is with C#, use the prebuilt libraries that allows you access to the Registry
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx

Mind you though, you only have Read/Write access to HKEY_LOCAL_USER, and READONLY to everything else.

Comment: The question specifically asks about running `regedit`. It does not ask about accessing the registry by any other means.

Comment: Which is why I put "Answer:" as well as provided an alternative :)

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/171917/force-a-program-to-run-without-administrator-privileges-or-uac shows a way how to run applications (including regedit) without elevating.

Answer (score 5):

You can run regedit without administrative privileges by launching it as a non-administrator. If you launch it as an administrator user, you get the UAC prompt, but if you launch it as a regular user, you get no prompt and most things outside of HKEY_CURRENT_USER are read-only.

regedit.exe is marked with `<requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />`, which does not always ask for admin permissions, only if the current user is an administrator.

If you really need to run regedit as an admin user without admin rights, according to [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/itprovistasecurity/thread/6b492608-7ea8-443a-a085-29fc22c72a5b), you can use the [Compatibility Administrator](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317510) tool to configure your system to ignore the `requestedExecutionLevel`.

Comment: This is not correct on Windows >= Vista. See @user2246674 answer.

Comment: @Echsecutor Did you try it? Did you create a non-admin account and run regedit under that user? I am pretty sure you didn't.

Comment: yes, I did. You can not run regedit on Windows 7 Enterprise SP 1 from a non-admin Account. It will ask for elevation immediately.

Comment: @Echsecutor I think I checked on Vista at the time, where it would ask for elevation immediately if run from an admin account in non-admin mode, but where it would not ask for elevation at all if run from a non-admin account. I checked on Windows 10 right now, and it still works that exact same way. I'll double-check Windows 7 later today, don't have access right now, but I'm very doubtful it changed and then changed back.

Comment: @Echsecutor Tested on Windows 7 (Home Premium, though I doubt that matters) now. Logged in as an administrator. Ran regedit. Got prompted for full privileges. Closed regedit. Created a brand new standard user named "Standard User". Ran cmd as that user, just to make sure that worked. It did. Ran regedit as that user. It started without any prompt for elevation, exactly as I described in my answer here. I stand by it, fully.

Comment: I am glad it works for you. As discussed in the link provided by user2246674, it seems to be somewhat unclear, under which circumstances you may run regedit as a standard user. Anyway, I can't on my machine and the same is obviously true in the original question and for user2246674. I can not see how your insisting on 'yes, I can!' is any helpful, sorry.

Comment: @Echsecutor Does that behaviour continue even if you create a brand new user, and double-checking at each step that that brand new user is not a member of any special group?

Comment: Data point: This solution *works* on my `Windows 7 Enterprise SP1`.

Answer (score 2):

A modern regedit.exe (i.e. Vista+ *with UAC on*) has the unfortunate notion that it must be run "as an administrator" - I'm not sure if it's technically true that it must be an "Administrator", but [this issue is a result of UAC](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/itprovistasecurity/thread/6b492608-7ea8-443a-a085-29fc22c72a5b) and failed elevation.

*This is a silly artificial restriction as the user has access (readonly) to most registry locations and write to HKCU*. However, other than disabling UAC, which requires admin permissions and may be inadvisable, I do not how this restriction on regedit.exe can be bypassed.

1. It should be possible to use [reg.exe](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html) (which is distributed with Windows), albeit without a nice UI.
2. Use a 3rd party registry editor/tool where this silly UAC elevation/restriction does not apply.
3. It may be possible to use regedit.exe *from Windows XP* which is not "UAC aware" - YMMV.
4. As suggested by sircapsalot, use managed API - perfect if already using C#.

Comment: The question specifically asks about running `regedit`. It does not ask about accessing the registry by any other means.

Comment: @KenWhite Which is why the first two paragraphs addressed the problem, what causes, and a link to additional reading on the subject. Feel free it ignore the suggestions at the end.

Comment: Ok thanks but how would i use REG.exe in my C# application without opening a new window?

Comment: @DanielJones [ProcessStartInfp.CreateNoWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow.aspx) can suppress the window from displaying - but if already in C#, consider using the managed API if at all possible as it can do everything that can be done with starting the reg.exe process. reg.exe is more useful for importing a .reg file or other administrative tasks.