# Admin rights when disabling Taskmanager

Tags: c#

How do I execute this code without administrator rights?

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System");

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    key.SetValue("DisableTaskMgr", 1); 
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Registry.CurrentUser.DeleteSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System");
    // Or you can change the key value to 0
}
```

Comment: You don't. What else can we help you with?

Comment: He means that privileges are there for a reason. Add more privileges to your user, so he could modify that key.

Comment: I mean exactly what I said. Your question was "How do I execute this code without administrator rights?". You don't execute that code without administrator rights. Can we help you with another question?

Comment: You already asked [basically this same question before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370317/accessing-regedit-without-admin-rights). You want to access administrator-protected registry keys without administrator access. This would violate security. Also, software should not be changing administrator policies. The administrator set the policy for a reason. If the administrator wants to change the policy, use the Group Policy system. That's what it's for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a manifest file and add the following code, this will elevate your program in higher privileged mode. Hence you can execute the program.

```
1. Add a new file to you project called App.manifest; by adding a new File from 
   Project.
2. Add following data to that file, rest it will do the magic.
```

Just replace your application name with YourAssemblyName. The important part is the section. Rest is auto generated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"
    xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"
    xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="YourAssemblyName" />
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator"
        uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</asmv1:assembly>
```

Comment: So I'm adding a folder in and then adding a class into that folder?

Comment: @DanielJones: Not actually. You just Right click on your project -> Choose Add New Item -> Select Manifest file. Then change your file as I have given above. But chnage only the Assembly Name & Security related changes.

Comment: I dont have a Manifest option, im using Visual Studio Desktop, is that a problem?

Comment: @DanielJones Can't you see the Application Manifest File, when you click on Add New Item from your Project explorer?

Comment: Oops sorry now i have it! do i replace everything in it?

Comment: What does it mean by YourClassName?

Comment: YourClassName actually refers to the class from where you are trying to invoke some code with higher prievilege. In your case where you try to write in Registry.

Comment: Thank you! I have it working now! I have another problem now... I have posted it... Can you have a look at it please? :)

Comment: Which one? Better you share the link here.