# Regedit only creates Key manually but not when called out of c#-program

Tags: c#, registry, regedit

Ive got a .reg file: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Informatik\Access\NetCode\SmartCard.reg" with the following content:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{6Z72B1AB-31CA-4852-9552-39E149C6D6D9}]
@="SmartCard.SmartCardValidator"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{6Z72B1AB-31CA-4852-9552-39E149C6D6D9}\InprocServer32]
@="mscoree.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Both"
"Class"="SmartCard.SmartCardValidator"
"Assembly"="SmartCard, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8eb9c4ad764487a4"
"RuntimeVersion"="v4.0.30319"
"CodeBase"="file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Informatik/Access/../NetCode/SmartCard.dll"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{6Z72B1AB-31CA-4852-9552-39E149C6D6D9}\InprocServer32\1.0.0.0]
"Class"="SmartCard.SmartCardValidator"
"Assembly"="SmartCard, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8eb9c4ad764487a4"
"RuntimeVersion"="v4.0.30319"
"CodeBase"="file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Informatik/Access/../NetCode/SmartCard.dll"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{6Z72B1AB-31CA-4852-9552-39E149C6D6D9}\ProgId]
@="SmartCard.SmartCardValidator"



[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{6Z72B1AB-31CA-4852-9552-39E149C6D6D9}]
@="SmartCard.SmartCardValidator"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{6Z72B1AB-31CA-4852-9552-39E149C6D6D9}\InprocServer32]
@="mscoree.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Both"
"Class"="SmartCard.SmartCardValidator"
"Assembly"="SmartCard, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8eb9c4ad764487a4"
"RuntimeVersion"="v4.0.30319"
"CodeBase"="file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Informatik/Access/../NetCode/SmartCard.dll"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{6Z72B1AB-31CA-4852-9552-39E149C6D6D9}\InprocServer32\1.0.0.0]
"Class"="SmartCard.SmartCardValidator"
"Assembly"="SmartCard, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8eb9c4ad764487a4"
"RuntimeVersion"="v4.0.30319"
"CodeBase"="file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Informatik/Access/../NetCode/SmartCard.dll"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{6Z72B1AB-31CA-4852-9552-39E149C6D6D9}\ProgId]
@="SmartCard.SmartCardValidator"
```

When I call the following code:

```
localesRegistryFile = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Informatik\Access\NetCode\SmartCard.reg";
Process regeditProcess = Process.Start("regedit.exe", "/s \"" + localesRegistryFile + "\"");
regeditProcess.WaitForExit();
```

the keys are sopposed to be created. But unfortunately only the keys in

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{6Z72B1AB-31CA-4852-9552-39E149C6D6D9}]
```

are created. The complete to section

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{6Z72B1AB-31CA-4852-9552-39E149C6D6D9}]
```

is not created. But when I double click "C:\Program Files (x86)\Informatik\Access\NetCode\SmartCard.reg"  in the explorer both sections are imported.

Ill already tried to:

- call the code out of the release version with no debugger involved.
- call regedit in without the /s tag => no change except of the security question before importing
- use cmd to call 
  regedit.exe /s "C:\Program Files (x86)\Informatik\Access\NetCode\SmartCard.reg"
  => works like the double click in explorer

This is very strange to me. Why only the second half of .reg works? What could be the reason for this behavior?

**Edit:**
After the answer I changed my code to this:

```
var commandLine = "/s \"" + localesRegistryFile + "\"";

var regeditFileName = "";
if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem && !Environment.Is64BitProcess)
{
    regeditFileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows), "regedit.exe");
}
else
{
    regeditFileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.SystemX86), "regedit.exe");
}
MessageBox.Show(regeditFileName + " 64Os: " + Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem.ToString() + " 64BitProzess: " + Environment.Is64BitProcess.ToString());
Process regeditProcess = Process.Start(regeditFileName, commandLine);
regeditProcess.WaitForExit();
```

This works on my computer but not on 2 other computers. The output is identical in all cases:

```
C:\WINDOWS\regedit.exe 64Os: True 64BitProzess: False
```

It seems like, Visual Studio 2015 or 2017 has something to do with the problem. I tried it on another computer where VS is installed and there both entries are inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are running regedit.exe from 32-bit application on a 64-bit system.
The regedit.exe executable located in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` is the 32 bit version, and the executable in `C:\Windows` is the 64 bit version.

So, view or edit 64-bit keys, you must use the 64-bit version of regedit.exe. That's the reason your registry keys are properly inserted when you double click on the reg file (explorer.exe is 64-bit program on your system).

Use this code to detect the proper version of the `regedit`.

```
var dir = "";
if(Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem && !Environment.Is64BitProcess)
    dir = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows), "regedit.exe");        
else
    dir = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.SystemX86), "regedit.exe");
```

Keep in mind that your launcher application needs to have admin privileges in order to write to registry.
Add this code to your Application Manifest file.

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Comment: You are on 64-bit system and your process is 32-bit. That's the reason you should use Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows. It should work that way.

Comment: It works if I remove the not so it looks like: "if(Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem && Environment.Is64BitProcess)"

Comment: I'm 64-bit os and no 64-bit process. So I have to use the else-path. Correct?

Comment: @EyIM: "You are on 64-bit system and your process is 32-bit. That's the reason you should use Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows." In your current code, in this case Environment.SpecialFolder.SystemX86 is used.

Comment: Unfortunately this seems only work on my machine. As I tried to use it on 2 other machines it did not work. I used the release version and this: "MessageBox.Show(regeditFileName + " 64Os: " + Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem.ToString() + " 64BitProzess: " + Environment.Is64BitProcess.ToString());" to print out the used version and it is: C:\Windows\regedit.exe 64Os: True 64BitProzess: False"

Comment: Please update the code in the question. Also, I would add a log file with the path you are running on the other machines. Are they 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: It seems like, that Visual Studio has something to do with the problem. I tried it on another computer where VS is installed and it worked there too.

Comment: Are you running the problem as an Administartor on the other computers?

Comment: No. The .reg is for registering a COM-Component without beeing an administrator.

Comment: So this is the issue. regedit.exe needs admin permissions to write to registry.

Comment: it does not. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{6Z72B1AB-31CA-4852-9552-39E149C6D6D9} is written on all machines and on the second development-computer there was no administrator either.

Comment: The answer is you can not run regedit.exe without admin. Maybe on some of the computes, you are default Admin without UAC. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16370362/1410246

Comment: This is not correct. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{6Z72B1AB-31CA-4852-9552-39E149C6D6D9} is written on all of the client machines. This worked for several month on 20 + computers. But anyway. This is not the point of my question. My question is why !only the upper half of the .reg-file! is written.